# GC on reassigned static object references

Tags: object, reference, static, garbage-collection

Say I have `obj = new myobject()`, where `obj` is declared as a static class field inside another, non-static class instance.  After a while, I create a new myobject on the same static variable `obj`, thus "overwriting" the original assignment.

Here are my questions:

1. Is the allocated object instance reliably released by GC, presumed it is not reachable from anywhere else any more?
2. Are there any differences if the field is declared non-static?
3. Does it make a difference to set it to null before reassigning the static var to a new instance?

Comment: Just think about what “unreachable” means and how irrelevant anything of the *past*, when the object was reachable, is to the state of being unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

> ... where `obj` is declared as a static class field inside another, non-static class instance.

This could mean one of two things; a `static` field, or an instance field of a `static` class.

The following applies to both cases, except as noted.

> 1) Is the allocated object instance reliably released by GC, presumed it is not reachable from anywhere else any more?

It depends on what you mean by "reliably".  It is not actually guaranteed that the GC will run (ever), or that it will find all unreachable objects in a given run, or that an unreachable object will be collected in the lifetime of a program.

But you generally don't need these things to be guaranteed.  All that really matters is that you won't run out of heap space because of some object that is unreachable<sup>1</sup>.

> 2) Are there any differences if the field is declared non-static?

This is where the issue I mentioned at the start comes into play:

- If we are talking about a field that it is an instance field of a `static` class, then it is *already* non-static.
- If we are talking about a `static` field versus an instance field, then there is a difference in the respective field lifetimes.  A `static` field is reachable for the duration of the application (if we ignore dynamically created classloaders).  An instance field lives as long as the object it is a member of.

> 3) Does it make a difference to set it to `null` before reassigning<sup>2</sup> the static var to a new instance?

It makes no difference whatsoever.

---

<sup>1 - We need to be a little careful here.  A JVM can trigger an "out of memory" event either because there isn't enough memory, or because the GC is spending too much time collecting garbage.  In the latter case, it is possible (at least in theory) that a given unreachable object won't be found before the event.  It is also possible to run a JVM with the Epsilon collector.  This collector never collects any garbage.</sup>

<sup>2 - Note: you assign a value to a variable, not the other way around.  You *could* also say that a variable *is assigned* a value.  But not what you wrote.  Using the correct words helps (your) understanding.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. So is it correct to say that everything boils down to the crucial question whether a referenced object is still reachable? If so, Implementation is irrelevant, just the resulting effect counts,  right? Then static declarations do not matter at all.

Comment: That is basically correct.  It is all about reachability.